# PHP $_post not getting the value of multi-input box with same name

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am using jquery show and hide method. If i use `$a=$_POST['a'];` ,Its getting empty value. Need help.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="a" value="" /> 
<input type="text" name="a" id="b"  value="" />
<input type="text" name="a" id="c"  value="" />
<input type="text" name="a" id="d" value="" />
```

Comment: Did you submit your form?

Comment: Just used `"name=a[]"` in your name attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `name="a[]"`. Since input field names are same so it should be `array` instead.

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <input type="text" name="a[]" id="a" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="a[]" id="b"  value="" />
    <input type="text" name="a[]" id="c"  value="" />
    <input type="text" name="a[]" id="d" value="" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**In test.php** to get the value

```
$values = $_POST['a'];

print '<pre>';
print_r($values);
print '</pre>';
```

**EDIT :**  Updated according to you comment. You used unnecessary concatenation `'".$a[$c]."'`. Just get the value of `$b`

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
if (is_array($a)) {
    foreach($a as $c => $b) {
        $a2 = $b;
            /*^^^^*/
        $db->query("INSERT INTO table(code1,code2) VALUES ('$user_id','$a2')");
    }
}
```

Comment: how will i use post and insert it

Comment: i tried this,but not working:    `$a=$_POST['a']; 
 if (is_array($a))
{
 foreach($a as $c => $b)
{
$a2='".$a[$c]."';
}`

Comment: `$db->query("INSERT INTO table(code1,code2)
    VALUES ('$user_id','$a2')");`

Comment: @vas_bar_code Update my post, hope it will help you.

Comment: I filled the second input box with some text.But `$a2` is empty when tried to insert.

Comment: **UPDATE:**I am getting only the first input box value,not others

Answer (score 1):

```
  <input type="text" name="a" id="a" value="" /> 
  <input type="text" name="a" id="b"  value="" />
  <input type="text" name="a" id="c"  value="" />
  <input type="text" name="a" id="d" value="" />

   in php

 echo $_POST['a'][0]; 
 echo $_POST['a'][1]; 
 echo $_POST['a'][2]; 
 echo $_POST['a'][3];
```